# javascript is removing backslashes from my strings?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mathjax

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/9707/)

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
this.observableString = ko.observable('When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$');
    this.regularString = 'When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$';

};
```

Both of which give me gibberish because the backslashes are replaced somehow before being rendered by MathJax.  If I use inline text, it works.  How can I save these strings without touching the backslashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `\` is the [escape character](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm) in JavaScript you have to escape it to get a backslash.

Use `\\` (escape the escape character) in place of just `\`.

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/9708/

Answer (score 4):

You need to double all the backslashes.  Javascript uses \ as an 'escape character', e.g. `'\n'` is interpreted as a one-character string containing a newline.